# Copy a specific cell data into column of other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets, named "Monthly" and "Index", in a workbook.

In Index, cell A1 will have a value after some calculations.

I need to copy that value into "Monthly" Column "J".

It shall be one by one using next row coding.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()    
Dim i As Integer    
a = Worksheets("Monthly").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a    
    Range("K" & i).Copy Worksheets("Rule of 78").Range("D6")       
    'Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Copy Range("C1")    
    Range("I" & i).Copy Worksheets("Rule of 78").Range("D7")    
    Range("E" & i).Copy Worksheets("Rule of 78").Range("D8")    
    Range("A" & i).Copy Worksheets("Rule of 78").Range("D10")    
    Worksheets("Index").Range("C2").Copy " How to paste in Monthly sheet 
    column J, for every row, C2 is different"
Next i    

End Sub
```

Comment: I have 3 sheets basically, for 2 i am done. from these 2 I get a value in 3rd sheet named as "Index" cell C2, this C2 will change every time calculation is run.
now i want that this C2 value get paste in sheet monthly, column J, for every row of column J, C2 will have different value

Comment: You keep overwriting the cell in every loop for the part you already wrote.

Comment: And to paste in Monthly Sheet you can do it just like you did in your code for "Rule of 78" what is your issue?

Comment: Actually the present coding is copying many rows data into a single cell for calculation
we say that there is a cell D6, all the row data from Column K is copying one by one and we are getting result in C2.
From this C2 single cell calue, i want to copy and paste value in to Column J before it is replaced

Comment: Still unclear: Why don t you just use `Worksheets("Index").Range("C2").Copy Worksheets("Monthly").Range("J" & i)`

Comment: It is not working , creating error in cell

Comment: what if i send you file, please

Answer (score 1):

Does "A1" have a formula? If so Excel is probably copying a formula, thus the error.

Try:

```
Worksheets("Index").Range("A1").Copy
Worksheets("Monthly").Range("J" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Edit: "A1" or "C2", I didn't get wich is giving you the error.

Comment: Thanks, yes A1 was containg some index match formula, thats why excel was showing error